# How to make Mediaplayer's getMaxAmplitude return faster (not zero)

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

For a project i have a lot of trouble with i encountered that the `getMaxAmplitude()` doesn't always return the real measured value but rather returns a '0' instead. 
For my project i require to get the sound amplitude 10 times per ms (10.000Hz)
At least. 
I put my results in an graph on my app: [image: Graph returning amplitude]
As you can see my actual sound level is only returned about once every 10-20ms (the pink/red dots are points where i've gotten a returned value).

Has anyone encountered this? Has anyone found a solution for this problem?